# How to perform difference between the columns for the given table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I have got a table with below columns

```
STOCK_NAME                                         TRADE_DATE TRADE_TYPE                                         QUANTITY_BOUGHT        QUANTITY_SOLD          TOTAL_AMOUNT_SOLD      TOTAL_AMOUNT_BOUGHT
-------------------------------------------------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
CACC                                               2020-04-08 buy                                                125                    0                      0                      41185
CACC                                               2020-04-08 sell                                               0                      125                    41031.25               0

HDK                                                2020-03-02 sell                                               0                      50                     59189.8                0
HDK                                                2020-03-05 buy                                                10                     0                      0                      11523.5
HDK                                                2020-06-03 sell                                               0                      10                     10248.5                0
MGH                                                2020-03-05 buy                                                1000                   0                      0                      52350
MGH                                                2020-04-07 buy                                                1000                   0                      0                      42500
MGH                                                2020-04-07 sell                                               0                      1000                   42750                  0
TNT                                                2020-05-19 buy                                                48                     0                      0                      19725.6
TNT                                                2020-06-01 buy                                                2                      0                      0                      995.2
TNT                                                2020-06-05 sell                                               0                      50                     28045.7                0
```

My intention is

1. To sum all the quantity that is sold and bought under a given stock_name and if the quantity_sold and quantity bought are same then I do difference between the Total_amount_bought and Total_amount_sold and can be called a net profit or net loss for that trade
2. If the quantity that is sold and bought are not the same for a given stock_name, let us take stock_name MGH the Total_amount_sold has to be subtracted from Total_amount_bought for the same quantity if the date of transaction are on the same date. To elaborate the 1000 quantity was bought and sold 1000 on the same date, in that case Total_amount_bought has to be subtracted from Total_amount_sold on the same date.
3. For the stock HDK the net profit/loss has to calculated for the stock where the quantity has been same. To elaborate quantity 10 was bought and sold so the relevant amounts have to be subtracted to get net profit/loss ignoring the other entry for HDK where there is another entry of quantity 50 which has to be ignored.

Kindly help. I have been struggling with this wrote a query to work for this:

```
SELECT SQ.STOCK_NAME, SQ.NP
FROM
(SELECT STOCK_NAME, TRADE_DATE, 
 SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_SOLD) - SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_BOUGHT) AS NP, 
 SUM(QUANTITY_BOUGHT) AS QB, SUM(QUANTITY_SOLD) AS QS
 FROM [STOCK_TRADING_dETAILS]
 GROUP BY STOCK_NAME, TRADE_DATE) SQ
 WHERE QB-QS = 0
```

but this covers transaction occurring on the same date, but does not cover transactions done on different date meaning Transactions for Stock_name TNT were not covered although the number of stock bought and sold are same. I have been struggling to incorporate this scenario with in the same query.

The final result set should be

```
STOCK_NAME                                         NET PROFIT/LOSS
-------------------------------------------------- ----------------------
MGH                                               250
CACC                                             -153.75
HDK                                              -1275.0
TNT                                               7324.9
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "but does not cover transactions done on different date" Then remove `TRADE_DATE` from your `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Jack the Ripper's advice and go by parts.

First get the profits when the stock bought and sold are the same, and put it on a CTE:

```
WITH TOTAL_PROFITS AS (
  SELECT STOCK_NAME, SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_SOLD) - SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_BOUGHT) AS PROFITS
  FROM STOCK_TRADING_DETAILS
  GROUP BY STOCK_NAME
  HAVING (QUANTITY_BOUGHT) = SUM(QUANTITY_SOLD)
)
.....
```

Then put on another CTE the query you have already prepared of profits for equal buys and sales at the same day:

```
WITH DAILY_PROFITS AS (
  SELECT SQ.STOCK_NAME, SQ.PROFIT
  FROM (SELECT STOCK_NAME, TRADE_DATE, 
               SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_SOLD) - SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_BOUGHT) AS PROFIT, 
               SUM(QUANTITY_BOUGHT) AS QB, SUM(QUANTITY_SOLD) AS QS
        FROM STOCK_TRADING_DETAILS
        GROUP BY STOCK_NAME, TRADE_DATE) SQ
  WHERE QB-QS = 0
)
.....
```

Now we build a new CTE with the results of the third case

```
WITH DAILY_BUYS AS (
  SELECT STOCK_NAME, TRADE_DATE, (QUANTITY_BOUGHT) AS QB, SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_BOUGHT) AS AB
  FROM STOCK_TRADING_DETAILS
  GROUP BY STOCK_NAME, TRADE_DATE
), 
DAILY_SALES AS (
  SELECT STOCK_NAME, TRADE_DATE, (QUANTITY_SOLD) AS QS, SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_SOLD) AS AS
  FROM STOCK_TRADING_DETAILS
  GROUP BY STOCK_NAME, TRADE_DATE
),
DIFFERENT_DATE_PROFITS (
  SELECT DAILY_BUYS.STOCK_NAME, DAILY_SALES.AS - DAILY_BUYS.AB AS PROFIT
  FROM DAILY_BUYS
       INNER JOIN DAILY_SALES ON DAILY_SALES.STOCK_NAME = DAILY_BUYS.STOCK_NAME AND
                                 DAILY_SALES.TRADE_DATE <> DAILY_BUYS.TRADE_DATE AND
                                 DAILY_SALES.QS = DAILY_BUYS.QB
) 
.....
```

And finally combine all those parts on the same query, unioning the total profits and the daily profits (of the products who already weren't on the total profits).

```
WITH TOTAL_PROFITS AS (
  SELECT STOCK_NAME, SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_SOLD) - SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_BOUGHT) AS PROFITS
  FROM STOCK_TRADING_DETAILS
  GROUP BY STOCK_NAME
  HAVING (QUANTITY_BOUGHT) = SUM(QUANTITY_SOLD)
),
DAILY_PROFITS AS (
  SELECT SQ.STOCK_NAME, SQ.PROFIT
  FROM (SELECT STOCK_NAME, TRADE_DATE, 
               SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_SOLD) - SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_BOUGHT) AS PROFIT, 
               SUM(QUANTITY_BOUGHT) AS QB, SUM(QUANTITY_SOLD) AS QS
        FROM STOCK_TRADING_DETAILS
        GROUP BY STOCK_NAME, TRADE_DATE) SQ
  WHERE QB-QS = 0
),
DAILY_BUYS AS (
  SELECT STOCK_NAME, (QUANTITY_BOUGHT) AS QB, SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_BOUGHT) AS AB
  FROM STOCK_TRADING_DETAILS
  GROUP BY STOCK_NAME, TRADE_DATE
), 
DAILY_SALES AS (
  SELECT STOCK_NAME, (QUANTITY_SOLD) AS QS, SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT_SOLD) AS AS
  FROM STOCK_TRADING_DETAILS
  GROUP BY STOCK_NAME, TRADE_DATE
),
DIFFERENT_DATE_PROFITS (
  SELECT DAILY_BUYS.STOCK_NAME, DAILY_SALES.AS - DAILY_BUYS.AB AS PROFIT
  FROM DAILY_BUYS
       INNER JOIN DAILY_SALES ON DAILY_SALES.STOCK_NAME = DAILY_BUYS.STOCK_NAME AND
                                 DAILY_SALES.QS = DAILY_BUYS.QB
) 
SELECT STOCK_NAME, PROFITS
FROM TOTAL_PROFITS
UNION ALL
SELECT STOCK_NAME, PROFIT
FROM DAILY_PROFITS
WHERE STOCK_NAME NOT IN (SELECT STOCK_NAME FROM TOTAL_PROFITS)
UNION ALL
SELECT STOCK_NAME, PROFITS
FROM DIFFERENT_DATE_PROFITS 
WHERE STOCK_NAME NOT IN (SELECT STOCK_NAME FROM TOTAL_PROFITS
                         UNION
                         SELECT STOCK_NAME FROM DAILY PROFITS)
```

Comment: Added point-3 and appended result set, made table structure concise and clarity to requirements. Please check my question again.

Comment: @Sree I don't think that you have really thought well this problem. If I were to add this new point 3), I'm certain that you will soon realize that you need a point 4) for when you have two different days that sum the same bought quantity than what was sold on a third date, and after that we will go on and on adding cases. Don't you think that it would be much simpler tot just return the profits of the products sold (against the same amount of buys for that product) independently of the day of the operation ?.

Comment: I agree with you, but if one were to implement point-3 how would one go about. I'm asking this out of curiosity. Kindly assist. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Sree same as the others. Go by simpler parts, put this new case on a separate CTE and UNION it to the result.  I will update the answer.

Comment: @Sree Now you have the answer updated, with the third point added.